# Obtaining the earliest date by day/month among different years

Tags: sql, oracle, function, date, monthcalendar

I have a list of dates:

Event dates

```
- 06/04/1998
- 12/08/1980
- 29/11/2010
- 16/06/2002
- 20/10/2007
- 10/07/2000
```

I wanna obtain the earliest event date by day/month among all these years. so the earliest is 06/04/1998 and if i wanna obtain the latest event date it is 29/11/2010. How do i write the syntax for this?

Comment: What happens if you have `01/01/2012` in there, which is the "earliest"?

Comment: So that shall be the earliest date :) i just want toget the earliest date by day/month among all the years.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MAX(date), MIN(date), YEAR(date) year, MONTH(date) month
FROM table
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

Note: This is pseudocode - you'll need to lookup what the correct function in oracle is to extract the year and month from a date.

You will also benefit from a function index on: `YEAR(date), MONTH(date), date`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date_column),
       EXTRACT( DAY   FROM date_column),
       EXTRACT( YEAR  FROM date_column),
       date_column
  FROM table
 ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

and to select the first record

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date_column),
               EXTRACT( DAY   FROM date_column),
               EXTRACT( YEAR  FROM date_column),
               date_column
          FROM table
         ORDER BY 1, 2, 3)
 WHERE rownum <= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand that you really do want the earliest date by day/month in any year, then an [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm) can do this:

```
select dt from (
    select dt,
        dense_rank() over (partition by 1 order by to_char(dt, 'MMDD'),
            to_char(dt, 'YYYY')) rn
    from t
)
where rn = 1;

DT
----------
06/04/1998
```

The inner `select` here is using [`dense_rank()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions052.htm) to assign a ranking to each date, based on an ordering I specified - there are other ways to do this but converting the day/month to a string seems to work, and I included the year to break ties if you have the same day/month in more than one year (guessing you'd want the earliest year in that case). Just that on its own, with a few extra dates added, looks like this:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
with t as (
    select to_date('06/04/1998') as dt from dual
    union all select to_date('12/08/1980') from dual
    union all select to_date('29/11/2010') from dual
    union all select to_date('16/06/2002') from dual
    union all select to_date('20/10/2007') from dual
    union all select to_date('10/07/2000') from dual
    union all select to_date('10/07/1999') from dual
    union all select to_date('06/04/1999') from dual
)
select dt,
    dense_rank() over (partition by 1 order by to_char(dt, 'MMDD'),
        to_char(dt, 'YYYY')) rn
from t;

DT         RN
---------- ----------
06/04/1998      1
06/04/1999      2
16/06/2002      3
10/07/1999      4
10/07/2000      5
12/08/1980      6
20/10/2007      7
29/11/2010      8

8 rows selected.
```

The outer select just picks the `dt` values with rank `rn = 1`.

If you want to find the latest, change the `order by` clauses to include `desc` so they're sorted in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

how about following:

select date from ... where rownum = 1 order by month(date) * 100 + day(date) desc

select date from ... where rownum = 1 order by month(date) * 100 + day(date) asc

Comment: Why add? You can put more than one column in an `order by`.

Comment: `limit` is not valid Oracle syntax.

Comment: I think what she wanted is to sort by day/month and ignore the year.

Comment: @Ian Xu yupp thats what i want

Comment: i don't know what's the limit in oracle. I believe oracle can do the similar thing. if not mind, anyone knows please point it out

Comment: @IanXu oracle returns rownum variable (sequence) with each result row, so to get first N records you would  
`SELECT ... WHERE ... ROWNUM <= N`

Comment: Your query is still incorrect; you cannot use a `rownum` predicate in the same query as an `order by`, without using a sub-query... plus the `month` and `year` functions do not exist.

Comment: @Ben I think the answer here is giving the OP the right concept, an idea to think about and use as they see fit. 100% precise answer is worse (IMHO) because it relieves the OP from the need to think, the end result is a monkey behind a keyboard and that, I suspect, is **NOT** what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If that list already has in table.

Just SELECT Max(fieldName) or Min(fieldName)

Comment: I used MIN(fieldname) but it gave me the earliest year instead of earliest date by day/month..